# why is there an error in the snapshot.data in main.dart inside body while trying to build app using newsapi?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, visual-studio-code

```dart
 FutureBuilder(
         future: client.getArticle(),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
           //let's check if we got a response or not
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
             //Now let's make a list of articles
             List<Article> articles = snapshot.data;
             return ListView.builder(
               //Now let's create our custom List tile
               itemCount: articles.length,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                   ListTile  (title: Text(articles[index].title),),
             );
           }
           return Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
           );
         },
       ),
     );    } }
```

The above code does not work as it shows an error.

Comment: Please share the exact error message too

Comment: A value of type 'List<Article>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Article>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Article>'.  @activout.se

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you got you need a cast like this:

```dart
List<Article> articles = (List<Article>)snapshot.data!;
```